# SQL Server 2016 DateDiff calculation across rows

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I have a table where each row is a separate phone call the columns are

```
start time (datetime) 
end time (datetime)
user name (string)
```

and a bunch of other unneeded columns.

I want to subtract the end time of row 1 from the start time of row 2 and so get the time between calls. Same from row 3 minus row 2 etc. So I get the output per user

```
start time call X ||  User Name  ||  time between end of call X and start of call X+1

 2018-03-23 10:00 ||  John Smith ||             450s
```

I know that SQL sever has a rownumber facility but I'm not sure how to do calculations that cut across rows.

Comment: You might take a look at LEAD/LAG.

Comment: agree with @SeanLange but we'd need sample data and expected output to help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sean. I didn't know lag existed. Exactly what I needed. I went with the below which is probably a bit of a mess but seems to do the job.

Cheers!

```
SELECT
[icstarttime]
,[usName]
,datediff(s,[previoustime],[icStartTime]) as [seconds between calls]

FROM(

SELECT 
      [icStartTime]

      ,[icEndTime]
      ,[usName]
      ,LAG([icEndTime], 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY [icendTime]) AS Previoustime
  FROM [iPR].[dbo].[InboundCalls] ic left join [iPR].[dbo].[iGeneralUsers] ig on ic.icUserID = ig.usID

  where icClientID = '5C381D91-F74C-45BD-9EF6-0B42CC7654C8'

  and [icType] = 17

  and [usName] = 'Zp'
  --and [icStartTime] > '2018-22-03'

  )T

  where Previoustime > '2018'
```